# how to compile apache,mysql and php in linux

Tags: linux

I have never used Linux OS. Want to know how we can start compiling Apache,Mysql and php in Linux and is it necessary to configure it.
I tried doing it by using cd/user/scr/httpd_2.0.09
Do we need to downloads the set up from google

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favour and don't try to compile your own webserver etc. ;)

Aside from the fact that it's a lot of work to set up the tools for compiling, resolve dependencies, and debug possible errors, you will have to do the same procedure with every tiny update – instead of simply getting a new version via your package manager.

If you use a common distribution, install the packages required for the so-called LAMP stack, and configure them properly. That will be hard enough for starters.

If you're using Ubuntu, have a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 0):

Actually installing binaries from repositories is less painful than compiling, but if you really want so, you may install Gentoo or other source-based distributive. I've simply described compilation of MySQL 5.5 [in my blog](http://nazar.serveblog.net/#installing-mysql-community-server-from-sources).
To compile packages on Debian based systems you need to install build-essential and cmake package (and maybe some other *-dev packages, which appears to be missing during source configure).
For example to compile MySQL 5.5 it is enough to run:

```
 cmake . #yep, with dot. Will prepare your source according to your system
 make
 make install #will install compiled binaries to system
```